# Add pagination to razor page with multiple search criteria

Tags: asp.net-core, pagination, razor-pages

My Index razor page contains a list of Projects, which can be filtered with multiple criteria from drop-down menus. I want to add a pagination to reduce the number of records displayed on the page when the number of records is higher than 10 (currently set to 3 for testing). I have searched and read many solutions, but have not found a way to integrate any of them in my current code.

I have created the PaginatedList.cs based on the standard Microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.0

My Index.cshtml.cs page contain the following code:

```
        public PaginatedList<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public IList<Project> Project { get; set; }
        public IList<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
        public SelectList FOOptions { get; set; }
        public string CurrentFOFilter { get; set; }
        public SelectList Options { get; set; }
        public string CurrentDSMFilter { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(List<int> fosearchString, List<int> dsmsearchString, int? pageIndex)
        {
            FOOptions = new SelectList(_context.Resource, nameof(Resource.Id), nameof(Resource.LongName));
            List<int> CurrentFOFilter = fosearchString;
            Options = new SelectList(_context.Resource, nameof(Resource.Id), nameof(Resource.LongName));
            List<int> CurrentDSMFilter = dsmsearchString;

            if (fosearchString.Count == 0 && dsmsearchString.Count == 0)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
                int pageSize = 3;

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project.Include(p => p.Resource).ToListAsync();
            }
            else if (fosearchString.Count != 0 && dsmsearchString.Count == 0)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
                int pageSize = 3;

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project
                    .Include(p => p.Resource)
                    .Where(s => fosearchString.Contains(s.FOId))
                .ToListAsync();
            }
            else if (fosearchString.Count == 0 && dsmsearchString.Count != 0)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
                int pageSize = 3;

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project
                    .Include(p => p.Resource)
                    .Where(s => dsmsearchString.Contains(s.DSMId))
                .ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
                int pageSize = 3;

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project
                    .Include(p => p.Resource)
                    .Where(s => fosearchString.Contains(s.FOId) && dsmsearchString.Contains(s.DSMId))
                .ToListAsync();

            }
            return Page();
        }
```

I would then also add something similar to the below to my Index.cshtml page:

```
@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.Projects.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.Projects.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}

<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Projects.PageIndex - 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFOFilter && @Model.CurrentDSMFilter"
   class="btn btn-primary @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Projects.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFOFilter && @Model.CurrentDSMFilter"
   class="btn btn-primary @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

I already have the form code for the filters as follows:

```
<form asp-page="./Index" method="get">
    <div class="dropdown col-4 no-gutters">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <select class="custom-select" name="fosearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFOFilter" asp-items="Model.FOOptions" selected="selected"><option value="">Filter by FO...</option></select><text>&nbsp;</text>
            <select class="custom-select" name="dsmsearchString" value="@Model.CurrentDSMFilter" asp-items="Model.Options" selected="selected"><option value="">Filter by DSM...</option></select><text>&nbsp;</text>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" /><text>&nbsp;</text><input type="submit" action="/Projects/Index" value="Back to full List" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I translate the code explained by Microsoft to include it in my code:

```
                Project = await _context.Project
                    .Include(p => p.Resource)
                    .Where(s => fosearchString.Contains(s.FOId) && dsmsearchString.Contains(s.DSMId))
                .ToListAsync();
```

If I modify my query as below Visual Studio flags many errors:

```
Projects = await PaginatedList<Project>.CreateAsync(
                Project.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);
```

Am I approaching this from the wrong angle? All I want is to add a pagination keeping my current code with the various search filters.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this tutorial could help: [How to build an efficient pagination system](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/38-How_to_build_an_efficient_pagination_system)

Comment: Thanks. It took me a little while to figure out where to add which part of the code and where to place the Count, so that the pagination is correct, but that did the trick. I will answer my own question with the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Laz Ziya. This answer is based on the information provided under the link http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/38-How_to_build_an_efficient_pagination_system

You need to install the LazZiya.TagHelpers nuget package using package manager console and add LazZiya.TagHelpers to _ViewImports.cshtml page as a prerequisite for the pagination to appear.

Here is the code in my Index.cshtml.cs PageModel

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ManyToManyRelationship.Data.ManyToManyRelationshipContext _context;


        //page number variable
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int P { get; set; } = 1;

        //page size variable
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int S { get; set; } = 10;

        public IndexModel(ManyToManyRelationship.Data.ManyToManyRelationshipContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        public IList<Project> Project { get; set; }
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; } = 0;
        public IList<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
        public SelectList FOOptions { get; set; }
        public string CurrentFOFilter { get; set; }
        public SelectList Options { get; set; }
        public string CurrentDSMFilter { get; set; }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(List<int> fosearchString, List<int> dsmsearchString)
        {
            FOOptions = new SelectList(_context.Resource, nameof(Resource.Id), nameof(Resource.LongName));
            List<int> CurrentFOFilter = fosearchString;
            Options = new SelectList(_context.Resource, nameof(Resource.Id), nameof(Resource.LongName));
            List<int> CurrentDSMFilter = dsmsearchString;

            if (fosearchString.Count == 0 && dsmsearchString.Count == 0)
            {
                Project = await _context.Project.Include(p => p.Resource).ToListAsync();
                TotalRecords = Project.Count();

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project.Include(p => p.Resource).Skip((P - 1) * S).Take(S).ToListAsync();

            }
            else if (fosearchString.Count != 0 && dsmsearchString.Count == 0)
            {
                Project = await _context.Project.Include(p => p.Resource).Where(s => fosearchString.Contains(s.FOId)).ToListAsync();
                TotalRecords = Project.Count();

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project
                    .Include(p => p.Resource)
                    .Where(s => fosearchString.Contains(s.FOId)).Skip((P - 1) * S).Take(S)
                .ToListAsync();

            }
            else if (fosearchString.Count == 0 && dsmsearchString.Count != 0)
            {
                Project = await _context.Project.Include(p => p.Resource).Where(s => dsmsearchString.Contains(s.DSMId)).ToListAsync();
                TotalRecords = Project.Count();

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project
                    .Include(p => p.Resource)
                    .Where(s => dsmsearchString.Contains(s.DSMId)).Skip((P - 1) * S).Take(S)
                .ToListAsync();

            }
            else
            {
                Project = await _context.Project.Include(p => p.Resource).Where(s => fosearchString.Contains(s.FOId) && dsmsearchString.Contains(s.DSMId)).ToListAsync();
                TotalRecords = Project.Count();

                Resources = await _context.Resource.ToListAsync();
                Project = await _context.Project
                    .Include(p => p.Resource)
                    .Where(s => fosearchString.Contains(s.FOId) && dsmsearchString.Contains(s.DSMId)).Skip((P - 1) * S).Take(S)
                .ToListAsync();

            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

and you need to add the paging code to the Index.cshtml page:

```
<paging page-no="Model.P"
        page-size="Model.S"
        total-records="Model.TotalRecords"
        query-string-value="@(Request.QueryString.Value)"
        show-prev-next="true"
        show-total-pages="true"
        show-total-records="true"
        show-page-size-nav="true"
        show-first-numbered-page="true"
        show-last-numbered-page="true">
</paging>
```

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you :)

Comment: btw,  `query-string-value="@Request.QueryString.Value"` will not be necessary with [LazZiya.TagHelpers v3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LazZiya.TagHelpers/3.1.0-preview1) _currently in preview mode_.

Comment: I am using same pager control but it doent work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964692/asp-net-core-3-1-razor-page-paging-not-working-as-intended